# return indices where two arrays of unequal size match

Tags: matlab

I have two column arrays x and y with matching numbers, but the first few numbers in y are missing. How can I index the rows where the numbers are missing in x?

For example, if I have

```
x = [1,5,6,5,8,8,10]'

y = [6,5,8,8,10]'
```

it should return:

```
z = 0,0,1,1,1,1,1
```

(where z is the same size as x)

Comment: You probably want [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html) (but I don't understand your expected result; shouldn't it be `[0 1 1 1 1 1 1]`?)

Comment: I think you're right, sorry. I did try ismember before, but with a larger array, and it keeps returning ones where there should be zeros. I must be doing something else wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is only missing numbers at the beginning using the `NaN` (Not a Number) term can be used to pad the array. After padding the array to equal sizes a comparison operation across the corresponding indices/elements respectively can be done. This in short will pad the array and then check if the corresponding elements match.

```
x = [1,5,6,5,8,8,10]';
y = [6,5,8,8,10]';

Length_Difference = length(x) - length(y);
Padding_Vector = NaN(1,Length_Difference).';
y = [Padding_Vector; y];

Matches = (x == y);
Matches.'
```

---

But if you're simply trying to see if the individual elements of `x` exist in `y` using `ismember()` will do the trick. To check for the opposite case use `ismember(y,x)`.

```
Matches = ismember(x,y);
Matches.'
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Can't `arrayfun(@(X,Y) X == Y,x,y)` be replaced by `x==y`?

Comment: Feel free to edit it into the answer if you want